# (Assembly) Is it possible to shr in the %eax register (x64) and still end up with a signed number?

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, x86-64

shr sets the highest order bit to zero. is it still possible to nevertheless end with a signed number? I have to cmpl with null and trigger a signed flag.

e.g.

```
shr %eax // I have %rax available if necessary
mov %eax -0x4(%rbp)
cmpl 0x0 -0x4(%rbp)
(then something that checks the signed flag)
```

Edit: Sorry for being unclear; my question is about if $rax or $eax can be set to anything such that the conditions were fulfilled.

Comment: I upvoted because this is the first time I have ever seen someone ask about assembly on StackOverflow. Props to you, freenet16.

Comment: @WilliamRosenbloom: They're fairly common you know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly

Comment: @Michael I'm sure there are a bunch in the annals of stack overflow but this is the first one I've seen come across my feed ever.

Comment: @freenet16: You should add a complete minimal example that can be used to reproduce the behavior you describe.

Comment: Are you actually looking for the [sar](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Flags/F77_0160_sar_instruction.htm) instruction?

Comment: Maybe it's part of a loop that jumps back skipping the `shr`?

Comment: Why the crap do you have to store to memory?  The value is right there in eax, waiting for you to `test eax,eax`.  Also, `shr` sets `SF` according to the result, so you can just branch or `setcc` on the `s` / `ns` condition without any `cmp` or `test`.  Of course, `shr` with a non-zero count will always clear `SF`, but `shr $0, %eax` doesn't update the flags.  (stupid x86 crazy CISC semantics make variable-count shifts slower because they need the old flags as an input operand in case the count is zero).

Comment: So is this a homework assignment to come up with a sequence where `shr <something>` can leave the sign bit set in `%eax`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `rax` available but the `cmp` actually uses `eax`, all you need to do is shift bit #32 of `rax` down to bit #31 which will then become the sign bit of `eax`:

```
movabsq $0x100000000, %rax
shr %rax
cmpl $0, %eax
```

```
(gdb) p/x $eax
$1 = 0x80000000
(gdb) i r eflags
eflags         0x286    [ PF SF IF ]
```

Comment: What about these bit numbers? Shouldn't it be bit #32 and bit #31?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jester. Sorry for being unclear; my question is about if $rax or $eax can be set to anything such that the conditions were fulfilled.

Comment: Answering before the 2nd cup is like trying to drive forward in neutral `:)`

Comment: In gdb you can `p $eflags`, and it still decodes it into `[ PF SF IF ]`, but doesn't show you the 0x286.  So it's like the `layout reg` mode.

Answer (score 1):

After shifting right some register by `shr`, the value in it is always positive. Checking for negative numbers is pointless.

If you want to use shift as a dividing by 2 and want to keep the sign of the result, you must use the `sar` instruction, that means "shift arithmetically right". This instruction fills bit 31 with the same bit that was there, this way preserving the sign of the number.